# Outlook losing toolbars on new email

Tags: windows-server-2003, microsoft-outlook-2003

Outlook 2003
Terminal Server 2003
Sometimes when clicking reply or new email the "Formatting" and "Standard" toolbars are missing and have to be reselected from "View -> toolbars"
Only one user has this problem.

There is never a need to change or add new toolbars so is it possible to lock the toolbars or delete the config file and start from fresh?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do if I'd be facing this issue, I'd start by recreating the Outlook profile since this is handle by Outlook files. If this doesn't fix it, check with another Windows profile. If it's ok then, recreate her/his Windows profile.

It's as simple as that but should fix it!

Comment: I've tried deleting the outcmd.dat file and the users profile form the Terminal server.

Comment: Did you delete the Outlook profile? And recreate it from scratch?

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and let you know the results as the user is out of the office and i can't test it at the moment.
Thanks